# Windows Server 2008 R2: *Show* all users at login screen

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, login

This question is essentially the opposite of:
[Windows Server 2008 R2: User account set to not show on login](https://serverfault.com/questions/90085/windows-server-2008-r2-user-account-set-to-not-show-on-login)

In my case, I'm trying to convince Windows 2008 R2 to *show* all (or, at least 2) users.

Previously, I did have registry entries under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
```

However, at this point the SpecialAccounts key has been deleted.


Within gpedit.msc, under:

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
```

My current "Interactive Logon" settings are:

- Display user information when the session is locked: User display name, domain and user names
- Do not display last user name: Disabled
- Do not require CTRL+ALT+Delete: Enabled

With these settings, upon first logging in all I get is text fields for Username and Password; no click-able icons.

...perhaps there's a setting elsewhere that I need to adjust in order to get click-able user icons for all users to show up on the logon screen?

Thanks in advance,

Nathan

Comment: `With these settings, upon first logging in all I get is text fields for Username and Password; no click-able icons.`  Would this be because no users have logged in yet, so the server doesn't have any accounts in its cache?

Comment: If I log in and then lock the server, I do see the icon for that user and a single field to enter that user's password. That behavior started once I enabled the "User display name, domain and user names" GPO. But if I log in as someone else and then lock the server, I see only the information for *that* user. (So, at no time are both users shown as click-able icons.)

Comment: This sounds like a lot of expected behavior.  What, precisely, are you trying to do here?

Comment: Perhaps it is; I was under the impression that the 2008r2 behavior was similar to Windows 7 in that it displayed all user logins on the welcome screen, as pictured in the first screenshot here: http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000541.htm . In my specific case, I have my regular account and a guest-like account (with specific permissions), and I'd like for both of those accounts to be displayed on the welcome page so the user (me vs. my wife/daughter) can select who to log in as without having to type in a user's name.